# Nodejs: I Don't get data of the request on .on('data'

Tags: node.js, request

I use Nodejs version 10.10.0 on Debian 9 with this simple code but it doesn't show any data in console nor response.

**code:**

```
const http = require('http');
const { parse } = require('querystring');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const { headers, method, url } = request;
  let body = [];
  request.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  }).on('data', (chunk) => {
    body.push(chunk);
  }).on('end', () => {
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();

    console.log(parse(body));

    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);


    response.write('body: ' + body);
    response.end();



  });
}).listen(3030); // Activates this server, listening on port 8080.
```

**result:**

```
{}
```

Comment: What request are you sending to the server?  GET or POST?  Show the exact request that is going to the server.  If it's a GET, there is no body sent, only headers.  I'd also suggest putting `console.log(chunk)` in the `data` event handler so you can see if that is ever getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comment. I am new to Nodejs and was thinking data should include either GET or POST requests' data; looks like it takes care of only POST requests and GET should be parsed from headers.